# If $z^{2023}=z+1$, prove $|z|\le 1$ if and only if the real part $\Re(z)\le -\frac{1}2$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers

$z$ is a complex number, if  $z^{2023}=z+1$, prove $|z|\le 1$ if and only if the real part $\Re(z)\le -\frac{1}2$

**My attempt**

If $|z|\le 1$, then $|z^{2023}|\le 1\rightarrow |z-(-1)|\le 1$.

Also, $|z|\le 1=|z^{2023}-z|=|z|\cdot|z^{2022}-1|$, since $z\neq 0$, we get

$$|z^{2023}-1|=|z|\le1\le |z^{2022}-1|\tag{1}$$

$z\neq 1$, divide $|z-1|$ on both sides.

$$|1+z+\cdots+z^{2022}|\le |1+z+\cdots+z^{2021}|$$

$$|z^{2022}|-|1+z+\cdots+z^{2021}|\le |1+z+\cdots+z^{2021}|$$

$$|z^{2022}|\le 2|1+z+\cdots+z^{2021}|$$

Multiply $|z-1|$ on both sides, we get:

$$|z^{2022}|\cdot |z-1|\le 2|z^{2022}-1|$$

I try to make a chain reaction from $(1)$, but seems not work. Can I have some hint? Thank you!

**Update: Solutions from the hint by @dxiv**

Conjugate, and multiply the two equations
$$\bar{z}^{2023}=\bar{z}+1,~~~\text{and}~~~z^{2023}=z+1$$
we get
$$|z|^{2\cdot 2023}=|z|^2+2\Re(z)+1$$
Finally,
$$|z|\le1\Longleftrightarrow |z|^{2\cdot 2023}\le|z|^2\Longleftrightarrow 2\Re(z)+1\le0\Longleftrightarrow \Re(z)\le -\frac{1}2$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: conjugate the equation, multiply with the original, rearrange $|z|^{2 \,\cdot\, 2023}= |z|^2 + 2 \operatorname{Re}(z) + 1$.